# I want to format a range of cells I've selected by clicking on a pre-formatted cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a schedule sheet where one of three colours will represent what's happening in the facility.  For ease of filling, I'd like the user to be able to select a range of cells, then click on the appropriate colour cell in the legend to apply that colour to their selected range.

Comment: That would be pretty easy to do in a sidebar.

Comment: You mean via conditional formatting?  Unfortunately, the way this sheet is set up, there's no data in the cells to base the formatting on.   The fact they're selected is the only way they're different than their neighbouring cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Just run setColorFromSidebar() and that will create a sidebar with four buttons on it.  Then select a range and click one of the buttons.  Put both functions in Code.gs file.

```
function setColorFromSidebar() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var html='<input type="button" value="Red" onClick="setBackground(\'#ff0000\');" />';
  html+='<br /><input type="button" value="Green" onClick="setBackground(\'#00ff00\');" />';
  html+='<br /><input type="button" value="Blue" onClick="setBackground(\'#0000ff\');" />';
  html+='<br /><input type="button" value="White" onClick="setBackground(\'#ffffff\');" />';
  html+='<script>function setBackground(color) { google.script.run.setBackGround(color);}</script>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}

function setBackGround(color) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  rg.setBackground(color);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That works great!  Any guidance on how to keep the sidebar active upon open/close?  I don't want users having to dig through menus to turn it on (they could just hit the paint bucket otherwise. ;) )

Comment: Load it onOpen().  It doesn't actually change  any data so I don't think any permissions are involved but I'm not sure.